# git: Unable to Clone Private Repositories, Error: Repositories not found

Tags: git, github, repository, git-clone

One of my friend added me on his Project on Github, as a collaborator. I am able to see the repo, but when I try to clone with this :

```
git clone https:/github.com/FriendsUserName/FriendsRepo.git
```

Gets errors:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository https:/github.com/FriendsUserName/FriendsRepo.git not found
```

I have setup multiple Github account successfully, from this article - [Github for work and play (multiple accounts)](http://ricardianambivalence.com/2013/09/22/github-for-work-and-play-multiple-accounts/#comment-12881)

Has anybody got this problem before?

I also tried to fork the repo and then clone. But still getting same error with clone.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I got myself in the exact same situation as the asker, so maybe the way I managed to do it will help someone.

The tutorial referred in the question involves creating aliases for the different Github account, e.g. `work.github.com` for your work account and `me.github.com` for your personal one.

So, in this case, the way you should clone your repo should be (assuming it's for your personal account) :

`git clone https:/me.github.com/FriendsUserName/FriendsRepo.git`

***However***, even that didn't work for me.

What did work was using the alias together with the ssh url for cloning, i.e.

`git clone git@me.github.com/FriendsUserName/FriendsRepo.git`

If this still doesn't work, try to see that you are indeed connecting with the correct account :

```
ssh -T git@me.github.com
```

The response to that should be :

`Hi <username for personal account here>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The error might occur in the permissions. Check if you have the permission to access.

Your friend must change the permisssion how this article:
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/

Also check your ssh access for validate if you re authenticated successfully for rule options ;)

ssh -T git@github.com

Comment: Above link is just document of adding collaborators, As I said my friend already added me as collaborator, I got the email notification. And ssh command is also working fine.

Comment: Have you checked the capitalization in the name of the repository? because repository names are case-sensitive

Comment: I know that. I did not type the URL, I copied it using GIthub's copy url feature.

Comment: Try it using HTTPS for rule an error ssh: git clone https://username:password@github.com/NAME/repo.git